# Multiply 2 columns within a DataFrame at different Datetimeindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to multiply 2 columns within the same DataFrame. The multiplication should not be at the same rows and hence at different DatetimeIndexes.

For instance:

```
a = df2['Column1'].loc['2021-04-26 00:00:00':'2021-04-26 08:00:00']
a
```

2021-04-26 00:00:00   -32.414135

2021-04-26 02:00:00   -20.799902

2021-04-26 04:00:00   -18.852000

2021-04-26 06:00:00   -18.297503

2021-04-26 08:00:00   -17.214313

````
b = df2['Column2'].loc['2021-04-26 02:00:00':'2021-04-26 08:00:00']
b```
````

2021-04-26 02:00:00   -0.358308

2021-04-26 04:00:00   -0.093650

2021-04-26 06:00:00   -0.029413

2021-04-26 08:00:00   -0.059199

*As a result I want a new column that will give:*

2021-04-26 00:00:00   NaN

2021-04-26 02:00:00   (-32.414135*(-0.358308))

2021-04-26 04:00:00   (-20.799902*(-0.093650))

2021-04-26 06:00:00   (-18.852000*(-0.029413))

2021-04-26 08:00:00   (-18.297503*(-0.059199))   #All as calculated values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dataframe operations are performed on the same row, as the result needs to be assigned to a specific row index.

What you can do here is to *shift* the values of one column first and multiply it with the values of the other one.

The following line should give you the result you specify:

```
df2["Column1"].shift(1) * df2["Column2"]
```

There are different ways how you can specify the offset for shifting – see the [documentation here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html).